# How to compare the files content of two folders, but excluse #if ... #endif

Tags: linux

I have two folders, say Folder_A and Folder_B. Most of the files in these two folder are of the same, but there are some files in Folder_B are modified with #if ... #endif sections.
Is there any linux command or batch can find such files in Folder_B?

Comment: Do the unwanted files have the same size in both folders? You could generate a directory listing of both directories and keep only the files with different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file1.c
foo bar
#ifdef foo
bar
#endif
qux
#ifdef foo2
bar2
#endif
qzzx
```

.

```
$ cat file2.c
foo bar
#ifdef foo_
bar_
#endif
qux
#ifdef foo3
bar3
#endif
quux
```

.

```
$ diff \
> <(awk '/^[[:space:]]*#if/,/^[[:space:]]*#endif/{next}1' file1.c) \
> <(awk '/^[[:space:]]*#if/,/^[[:space:]]*#endif/{next}1' file2.c)
3c3
< qzzx
---
> quux
```